# i have taken datepicker dialog. i want to restrict to select date from current date till its next 3 months

Tags: android, datepickerdialog

```
public void DateDialog() {
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            long timeInMilliseconds = 0;
            String givenDateString = "Tue Jun 23 16:08:28 GMT+05:30 2016";
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
            try {
                Date mDate = sdf.parse(givenDateString);
                timeInMilliseconds = mDate.getTime();
                System.out.println("Date in milli :: " + timeInMilliseconds);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            view.setMaxDate(timeInMilliseconds);
            datePicker.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + year);
        }
    };

    DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, listener, year, month, day);
    dpDialog.show();

}
```

> i have taken datepicker dialog. i want to restrict to select date from current date till its next 3 months

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();//get the current day
    calendar.add(Calendar.MONTH,3);
    long afterThreeMonthsinMilli=calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    DatePickerDialog dpDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    dpDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(afterThreeMonthsinMilli);
    dpDialog.show();
```

Comment: it is working fine but how to disable specific date@AndroidGeeks

Answer (score 0):

You can set MaxDate and MinDate restriction to your datepicker

```
setMinDate(long minDate)

setMaxDate(long maxDate)
```

Get your Current Date by this :

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
    int mDay = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), mMonth = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), mYear = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

And Check Whether select data i.e. `myMonth < mMonth+3` or not.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing for one of my project. I believe you're using a library here same as I did. Here is how I achieved it :

```
Calendar currentdate= Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar lastdate = Calendar.getInstance();
            lastdate.set(currentdate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentdate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + 90);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(HomeActivity.this, currentdate.get(Calendar.YEAR), currentdate.get(Calendar.MONTH), currentdate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
            datePickerDialog.setMinDate(currentdate);
            datePickerDialog.setMaxDate(lastdate);
            datePickerDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "yourtag");
```